# Nagios check_procs returns wrong value when called from NRPE

Tags: linux, process, nagios, nrpe

I have added the following line in nrpe.conf of a monitored server say named myserver:

```
command[check_mysrv_process]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -c 1: -C java -a mysrv
```

which works locally as expected:

```
myserver> /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs -c 1: -C java -a mysrv
PROCS OK: 1 process with command name 'java', args 'mysrv'
```

However when I run the check through nrpe from my nagios server I get a zero output whatever the number of processes with the specific patterns will be (usually 0 or 1):

```
mynagiosserver>/opt/nagios/libexec/check_nrpe -H myserver -u -c check_mysrv_process
PROCS CRITICAL: 0 processes with command name 'java', args 'mysrv'
```

More Details:

- NRPE version = 2.12
- Nagios Plugins version = 1.4.16
- OS Type: SLES 11.3
- The specific process name that contains mysrv is a long one.

**EDIT**

When doing `cat /proc/pid of nrpe/environ` I get the following line:

CONSOLE=/dev/consoleSELINUX_INIT=YESROOTFS_FSTYPE=ext3SHELL=/bin/shTERM=linuxROOTFS_FSCK=0crashkernel=256M-:128MLC_ALL=POSIXINIT_VERSION=sysvinit-2.86REDIRECT=/dev/tty1COLUMNS=96PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbinvga=0x314DO_CONFIRM=RUNLEVEL=5PWD=/SPLASHCFG=/etc/bootsplash/themes/SLES/config/bootsplash-800x600.cfgPREVLEVEL=NLINES=33HOME=/SHLVL=2splash=silentSPLASH=yesROOTFS_BLKDEV=/dev/sda2_=/sbin/startprocDAEMON=/usr/sbin/nrpe

Comment: Does the specific process name contain spaces or anything else that could need escaping in `nrpe.cfg`?

Comment: Yes it contains spaces, it is an application server process.

Comment: Try escaping the spaces with backslashes (e.g. `this\ is\ my\ process\ name`).

Comment: I do not know what the process name exactly is: it has the pattern <path>/java <arg1> <arg2> ... <argn> mysrv, but I have no idea what the args are each time. I just want the check_procs to check for a process with that name pattern (and it works locally).

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought you mean that you had substituted those argument to anonymise your question.

Comment: Can you post the output for `cat /proc/pid of nrpe/environ` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This makes me think about a reported Bug caused by the `COLUMN` environment variable.

Here, you have `COLUMNS=96`.

This means that any process command line that exceeds `COLUMN` value will be lost.

AS you said that your process name is long, you could be facing this issue.

You can try to increase your `COLUMN` variable in your command definition in `nrpe.cfg` :

```
command[check_myprogram_proc]=COLUMN=256 /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_procs ...
```

Reference : http://christoph-probst.com/article.php/20110718143604605

Comment: Ok, this worked but with setting "command[check_myprogram_proc]=COLUMNS=4000 ...", because the specific process names are more than 3000 characters long. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @trikelef 3000 ? Wow Impressive ! You should have specified this in your first question because it is not so common ;)